# How Can I Partition Rows in Cases When the Data is Greater than Other Values of the Same Category

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerquery

I am using ROW NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY) to obtain a numerical index of the first occurring incident a customer purchased a product.

Using the SQL query of:

```
SELECT

ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY
[Customer Name]
ORDER BY
[Created Date] ) AS Partition,

[Customer Name],

[Created Date]

FROM Database
```

My data populates as such:

**Current Table**

[image: Current Data]

**My Question**

I would like my data to partition additionally by the date. But only if the next date is greater than 60 days from the prior day. The numerical list would reset every 60 days. This Table would populate like this:

**Ideal Data**

[image: Ideal Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()` and a cumulative sum to define the groups:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_createddate > dateadd(day, -60, createddate) then 0 else 1 end) over  (partition by customername order by createddate) as grp
from (select t.*,
             lag(createddate) over (partition by customername order by createddate) as prev_createddate
      from t
     ) t;
```

Then use `row_number()` within each group:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by customername, grp order by createddate) as mypartition
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_createddate > dateadd(day, -60, createddate) then 0 else 1 end) over  (partition by customername order by createddate) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(createddate) over (partition by customername order by createddate) as prev_createddate
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Note that `partition` is a very poor name for a column because it is a SQL key word.

Comment: This worked very well! Thank you. I also appreciate the advise on using the word partition. In my real data I used something else but the advice is valuable.